# Accessing logs for ant

Tags: ant, installation, phpunit

I am trying to install a project from github using phpunit. The project uses composer to install the dependencies. 
When I run ant to build the project, I get a simple error message, but I would like to access more complete logs of ant. Is it accessible ?

Best,
Mehdi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html

For example using:

```
-verbose, -v
```

is quite popular to see what ANT does and how it does resolve dependencies.

Sebastian